# Using Travis with R and rJava

Tags: r, travis-ci, rjava

I have an R package which depends on rJava. I am using the R support for travis

```
language: r

sudo: required

warnings_are_errors: true

r_github_packages:
 - keboola/redshift-r-client
```

But it fails with error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Complete log: https://travis-ci.org/keboola/provisioning-r-client/builds/61021633

I tried adding:

```
apt_packages:
 - openjdk-7-jre
```

or

```
jdk:
- oraclejdk8
```

But none seems to have any effect.

### Solution 1:

```
language: r

sudo: required

apt_packages:
 - r-cran-rjava
```

### Solution 2:

```
language: r

sudo: required

apt_packages:
 - openjdk-7-jre

before_install:
 - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
 - export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
 - export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
 - sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to install `r-cran-rjava` directly via `apt-get`.

There are a number of questions here on SO related to `r-cran-rjava` so glancing at those may help too.  The `Build-Depends` for this package currently are `default-jdk` and the `Depends` is on `openjdk-7-jre | default-jre`.  Relying on the package should help you there though.

FWIW I still use the previous Travis setup as I find it loads faster.

Comment: Great, using r-cran-java seems to solve the problem, in the mean time: the following also seems to do the trick: apt_packages:
 - openjdk-7-jre

before_install:
 - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
 - export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
 - export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
 - sudo R CMD javareconf

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, and thanks for accepting the answer.  You may want to consider upvoting it too.    And the comment may be better as an edit to the question...

Comment: done, I sort of forgot that comments lose formatting :]

Comment: That is a much better reference now!

Comment: I don't get it, what do you mean by "install r-cran-rjava directly via apt-get" exactly? How do I do that?

Comment: That refers to usage of the package management system on a Debian or Ubuntu based Linux machine, and `apt-get` (or now `apt`) is the standard interface.  Please google, or search on StackOverflow, for any terms unfamiliar for you.  And needless to say, this does not apply to Windows or Mac.  But the OP was using Travis, and that runs on top of Ubuntu.