# How to configure a .travis.yml for a package that depends on rJava?

Tags: r, travis-ci, rjava

I (and some colleagues) have been working on a package that depends on rJava. The program we connect to needs Java 11+ to run, and we're running into some problems while trying to configure the .travis.yml file.

I have tried to follow the solutions of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012982/using-travis-with-r-and-rjava) (while adapting them to Java 11) but none seem to work. First I tried:

```
language: r
warnings_are_errors: true
sudo: required
cache: packages

apt_packages:
  - r-cran-rjava
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Failed with error:  ‘.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:

  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)

  error: unable to load shared object '/home/travis/R/Library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':

  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory’
```

Then I tried following the second approach:

```
language: r
warnings_are_errors: true
sudo: required
cache: packages

apt_packages:
  - default-jdk

before_install:
  - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
  - export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
  - export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib
  - sudo R CMD javareconf
```

To what I'm met with this error message:

```
sudo: R: command not found

The command "sudo R CMD javareconf" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

I have tried not using the `sudo`, but then I get that I don't have the required permissions.

I feel like the solution might be fairly obvious, but I have been stuck on this for quite a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `R` is in the user's PATH, but `sudo` ignores it and only looks in a few system locations. This can be solved easily by resolving the full path at the user level:

```
  - sudo $(which R) CMD javareconf
```

This inserts the full path to R into the sudo command.

Note that the `javareconf` script seems smart enough to detect Java in the standard locations, so it isn't necessary to export `JAVA_HOME`, `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before calling it.

I ended up with the following `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: r
cache: packages
warnings_are_errors: true
sudo: required

apt_packages:
  - r-cran-rjava

before_install:
  - sudo $(which R) CMD javareconf
```

Comment: Note that this seems to install java-8-openjdk, not 11. But it solves both error messages you encountered.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. I actually only need jre 11, not necessarily jdk 11, and I realized that r-cran-rjava installs it, so it should be alright.